# How to parse big XML in google cloud function efficiently?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, xml-parsing

I have to extract data from XML files with the size of several hundreds of MB in a Google Cloud Function and I was wondering if there are any best practices?

Since I am used to nodejs I was looking at some popular libraries like [fast-xml-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) but it seems cumbersome if you only want specific data from a huge xml. I am also not sure if there are any performance issues when the XML is too big. Overall this does not feel like the best solution to parse and extract data from huge XMLs.

Then I was wondering if I could use [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) for this task where I simple convert the xml to json and throw it into a Dataset where I then can use a query to retrieve the data I want.

Another solution could be to use python for the job since it is good in [parsing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and extracting data from a XML so even though I have no experience in python I was wondering if this path could still be
the best solution?

If anything above does not make sense or if one solution is preferable to the other or if anyone can share any insights I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-load-xml-data-into-bigquery-using-python-dataflow-fd1580e4af48) in which they discuss how to load XML data into BigQuery using Python Dataflow. I think that this approach may work in your situation.

Basically what they suggest is:

- To parse the xml into a Python dictionary using the package [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/).
- Specify a schema of the output table in BigQuery.
- Use a [Beam pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/beam-creating-a-pipeline) to take an XML file and use it to populate a BigQuery table.

Comment: thanks, I was wondering if this also works with nodejs and without defining a schema first. basically just convert everything to json and put it in BIgQuery and figure out the rest from there

Comment: I'm glad that the answer was helpful. If you could accept it I would appreciate it.